# Comment body field is missing

Tags: nodes

I enabled the forum module, and when I add a comment on a forum post, there is no body field. I disabled both the Comment and the Forum modules, and re-installed them, but I still have the same problem.

If I manually create a body field (field_comment_body), I get the following error message:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$comment_body in comment_admin_overview() (line 107 of /var/www/lms/modules/comment/comment.admin.inc).

Is there any solution to make the comment body appear as it happens with other content types?

Answer (score 1):

1. disable comment module
2. uninstall comment module
3. enable comment module

Comment: While it might answer OPs question, it lacks 2 important things: 1) explanation why and how would it work to solve OP's issue and 2) information that it would delete all comments posted so far.

Comment: Patch here: [https://www.drupal.org/node/2717717](https://www.drupal.org/node/2717717)